# How to prove this function is Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

$u,v\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $p(v)$ is bounded and non-negative, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}p(v)dv=1$, prove $f(u,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left[\nabla^\perp\ln||u-v||\right]p(v)dv$ (Here $\nabla$ is gradient operator ,the vector $\mathbf{a}^\perp$ is obtained by rotating vector $\mathbf{a}$ by 90 degrees) satisfies the condition

$\exists C>0, \forall u_1,u_2\in\mathbb{R}^2,t\ge0:$
$$
||f(u_1,t)-f(u_2,t)||\le C||u_1-u_2||
$$

prove: Denote $g(x)=\nabla^\perp\ln||x||$, $f(u,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}g(u-v)p(v)dv$. Let $\varepsilon<\frac{||u_1-u_2||}{3}$, and we have
$$
\begin{split}
&||f(u_1,t)-f(u_2,t)||\\
=&||\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}g(u_1-v)p(v)dv-\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}g(u_2-v)p(v)dv||\\
\le&||\int_{\mathbb{R}^2\backslash[B(u_1,\varepsilon)\cup B(u_2,\varepsilon)]}[g(u_1-v)-g(u_2-v)]p(v)dv||\\
&+||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}g(u_1-v)p(v)dv||+||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}g(u_2-v)p(v)dv||\\
&+||\int_{B(u_2,\varepsilon)}g(u_1-v)p(v)dv||+||\int_{B(u_2,\varepsilon)}g(u_2-v)p(v)dv||\\
%=&I_1+I_2+I_3
\end{split}
$$

Therefore, for the first part above, we know $u_1-v\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash [B(0,\varepsilon)\cup B(u_1-u_2,\varepsilon)]$ and what I concerned is $u_1-v\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash B(0,\varepsilon)$. Then, similarly, $u_2-v\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash B(0,\varepsilon)$. Then we can use the lip condition of $g(x)=\nabla^\perp\ln||x||$ in $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash B(0,\varepsilon)$:

$$
\begin{split}
&||\int_{\mathbb{R}^2\backslash [B(u_1,\varepsilon)\cup B(u_2,\varepsilon)]}[g(u_1-v)-g(u_2-v)]p(v)dv||\\
&\le||\int_{\mathbb{R}^2\backslash [B(u_1,\varepsilon)\cup B(u_2,\varepsilon)]}||g(u_1-v)-g(u_2-v)||p(v)dv||\\
&\le||\int_{\mathbb{R}^2\backslash [B(u_1,\varepsilon)\cup B(u_2,\varepsilon)]}C||(u_1-v)-(u_2-v)||p(v)dv||\\
&\le C||u_1-u_2||
\end{split}
$$

For $||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}g(u_1-v)p(v)dv||$, suppose $p(v)$ is bounded, i.e. $p(v)\le C_0$. Then we have

$$
\begin{split}
&||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}g(u_1-v)p(v)dv||\le C_0||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}||g(u_1-v)||dv||
=C_0||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}||\frac{(u_1-v)^\perp}{||u_1-v||^2}||dv||\\
\le&C_0||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}\frac{1}{||u_1-v||}dv||
=C_0\int_{B(0,\varepsilon)}\frac{1}{||v||}dv=C_0\int_0^{\varepsilon}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\rho}\rho dv=2\pi C_0\varepsilon
\end{split}
$$

Similarly, $||\int_{B(u_2,\varepsilon)}g(u_2-v)p(v)dv||<2\pi C_0\varepsilon$

In conclusion, let $\varepsilon\to0$ , then
$$
\begin{split}
&\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}g(u_1-v)p(v)dv||=\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}g(u_2-v)p(v)dv||\\
=&\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||\int_{B(u_2,\varepsilon)}g(u_1-v)p(v)dv||=\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||\int_{B(u_2,\varepsilon)}g(u_2-v)p(v)dv||=0
\end{split}
$$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
&\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||f(u_1,t)-f(u_2,t)||\\
\le&\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||\int_{\mathbb{R}^2\backslash [B(u_1,\varepsilon)\cup B(u_2,\varepsilon)]}[g(u_1-v)-g(u_2-v)]p(v)dv||\\
&+\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}g(u_1-v)p(v)dv||+\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||\int_{B(u_1,\varepsilon)}g(u_2-v)p(v)dv||\\
&+\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||\int_{B(u_2,\varepsilon)}g(u_1-v)p(v)dv||+\underset{\varepsilon\to0}{\lim}||\int_{B(u_2,\varepsilon)}g(u_2-v)p(v)dv||\\
\le&C||u_1-u_2||
%=&I_1+I_2+I_3
\end{split}
$$

**But**

In fact $C=C(\varepsilon)$, and $C\to\infty$ when $\varepsilon\to0$.

So, how can I modify this method and get the solution?

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: Just Euclidean distance

Comment: x=(a,b) and ||x||=(a^2+b^2)^1/2